# Does the glued trees problem separate search from decision in BQP?

Tags: oracles, glued-trees

Back in 2021, Aaronson had [collated](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.06917) a number of outstanding problems in quantum query complexity. The tenth problem on the list relates to the famous "[glued trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209131)" algorithm of Childs, Cleve, Deotto, Farhi, Gutmann, and Spielman, which can find (the label of) an EXIT node in a particular graph exponentially faster than a classical algorithm, by having a particle diffuse from left to right while tunnelling through the middle. Aaronson asks:

> **Problem 10** *Suppose, however, that we actually want to find a path from left to right. Does even a quantum computer need $2^{\Omega(n)}$ queries for that task?*

According to [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/to-move-fast-quantum-maze-solvers-must-forget-the-past-20230720/) and accompanying podcast, Quanta magazine provides:

> *Quantum algorithms can find their way out of mazes exponentially faster than classical ones, at the cost of forgetting the paths they took. A new result suggests that the trade-off may be inevitable.*

The article summarizes a line of work on "snake walks" culminating in Childs, Coudron, and Gilani's 2022 [no-go](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12447) paper.

**Can we say that glued trees provides an oracle separation wherein searching (for a path from left to right) is strictly harder than deciding (whether a path exists, or some other specific property of the exit node?)**

Aaronson suggested that this kind of problem is akin to wave-particle duality - we can know the name of the exit node only if we don't ask which path the particle took.

Comment: What do you expect from an answer, beyong quoting the abstract of the 2022 paper: *"We show that a natural class of efficient quantum algorithms provably cannot find a path from ENTRANCE to EXIT."*

Comment: @NorbertSchuch thanks - pls. see edit for small change in emphasis.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK this is not about deciding, but about finding the EXIT node? (Though probably deciding its existence is also fine.)

Comment: The abstract says *"Specifically, we consider algorithms that, within each branch of their superposition, always store a set of vertex labels that form a connected subgraph including the ENTRANCE, and that only provide these vertex labels as inputs to the oracle."* -- so I guess in that oracle setting yes, but possibly not in a more general oracle setting.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Or, deciding some specific property of its label?  For example the specific problem from the 2002 paper is to find the name of the exit node, so we could turn it into a decision problem by asking whether the name ends in "000" or something.